# Testing function that interacts with Django Rest Framework API using python mock library

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I want to unit test a module that interacts with an API built with Django Rest Framework. To do that I'm using python mock library. As I'm not experienced using mocks to test interaction with an API, I'm having problems.

The function that sends an object to an API endpoint is this (in short):

```
def send_experiment_to_portal(experiment: Experiment):
    rest = RestApiClient()

    if not rest.active:
        return None

    # general params
    params = {"nes_id": str(experiment.id),
              "title": experiment.title,
              "description": experiment.description,
              "data_acquisition_done":
                  str(experiment.data_acquisition_is_concluded),
              "project_url": experiment.source_code_url,
              "ethics_committee_url": experiment.ethics_committee_project_url
              }

    action_keys = ['experiments', 'create']

    portal_experiment = rest.client.action(
        rest.schema, action_keys, params=params,
    )

return portal_experiment
```

The `RestAPIClient` is the class that authenticates to the API:

```
class RestApiClient(object):
    client = None
    schema = None
    active = False

    def __init__(self):
        auth = coreapi.auth.BasicAuthentication(
            username=settings.PORTAL_API['USER'],
            password=settings.PORTAL_API['PASSWORD']
        )
        self.client = coreapi.Client(auth=auth)

        try:
            url = settings.PORTAL_API['URL'] + \
                  (
                      ':' + settings.PORTAL_API['PORT'] if
                      settings.PORTAL_API['PORT'] else ''
                  ) \
                  + '/api/schema/'

            self.schema = self.client.get(url)
            self.active = True
        except:
            self.active = False
```

The `RestApiClient` class is using the `coreapi` client module to connect to the API.

So, at the end, I'm starting from test if the `params` argument in `rest.client.action` has the keys/values that are foreseen by the API using python mock library.

I'm starting writing the initial test like:

```
class PortalAPITest(TestCase):

    @patch('experiment.portal.RestApiClient')
    def test_send_experiment_to_portal(self, mockRestApiClientClass):
        research_project = ObjectsFactory.create_research_project()
        experiment = ObjectsFactory.create_experiment(research_project)

        result = send_experiment_to_portal(experiment)
```

So when I debug the test, looking inside the `send_experiment_to_portal` function `rest.client.action.call_args` has the value:

```
call(<MagicMock name='RestApiClient().schema' id='139922756141240'>, ['expreiments', 'create'], params={'description': 'Descricao do Experimento-Update', 'ethics_committee_url': None, 'project_url': None, 'title': 'Experimento-Update', 'nes_id': '37', 'data_acquisition_done': 'False'})
```

But `mockRestApiClientClass.client.action.call_args` has `None`. I suspect that I'm making wrong. I should mock rest.client.action and not the `RestApiClient` class.

Trying to use `result` value does not work too.

The value of result is

```
<MagicMock name='RestApiClient().client.action()' id='139821809672144'>
```

and `result.call_args` is `None` too.

But how to do that? How to get the mocking `rest` instance outside `send_experiment_to_portal` function?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a couple of days I could find a solution.

Mocking `RestApiClient` returns the mock of the class not its value, that is the value of `rest` variable. We get the `rest` value calling `return_value` from the mock object.

So, we have to call `mockRestApiClientClass.return_value` instead of `mockRestApiClientClass`.

By doing that we have access to the `rest` methods and attributes called from inside `send_experiment_end_message_to_portal`, and then
`mockRestApiClientClass.return_value.client.action.call_args` will have the same content of the observed `rest` content inside `send_experiment_end_message_to_portal` function context.